# unpatented one-way encryption algorithm

Tags: encryption, hash

I am looking for a simple unpatented one-way encryption algorithm, preferably in c.
I would like to use it to validate passwords.

Comment: In my jurisdiction there are there are no software patents. What about yours?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[SHA-1 and the rest of its family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1)  were patented by the US government which "has released the patent under a royalty free license". Many public-domain implementations [may be found through Google](http://www.google.ca/search?q=sha+c+implementation). `:-)`

Answer (score 3):

The correct name for 'one-way encryption algorithm' is 'hashing algorithm' (you did mean a way to 'scramble' a password so that it can never be recovered, right?)

Do not use md5 in modern applications, successful attacks on it have been showing up since 2004 (see http://www.doxpara.com/md5_someday.pdf for references). Use the SHA family.

Comment: A true 'one-way encryption algorithm' would be to discard the data and instead pipe in from /dev/random.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

In fact using a hash is not enought. you should use a [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) to limit them and a more advanced technique such as [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) limits the possibilities of guessing the password

Answer (score 1):

just use the crypt(3) function

here's the [background](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(Unix))

Answer (score 1):

SHA-1 seems like a good suggestion, or, if you believe that SHA-1 is close to being cracked, one of the SHA-2 family.

You may feel that MD5 isn't "safe" enough.

Answer (score 0):

MD5 has suited me fine so far.

Answer (score 0):

MD5 and SHA512 (or another SHA-2 variant) both have theoretical vulnerabilities identified in them.  I don't think SHA has yet been demonstrated as broken but the possability exists.  Whirlpool is a royalty free hash algorithm that has (as yet) not shown any weakness.
[This page](http://paginas.terra.com.br/informatica/paulobarreto/WhirlpoolPage.html) has a link to the C reference implementation.